# traefik not respecting frontend rule

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I am trying to deploy multiple apps on my docker host and have traefik route traffic based on hostnames to the different apps

I am using docker-compose for all my docker containers

Here is my `traeffik.yaml` file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    networks:
      - traefik_network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
  traefik_network:
     name: traefik_network
```

here is my `wpapp1.yaml` file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - wpapp1_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     container_name: wpapp1_mysql
     networks:
       - traefik_network
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wpapp1
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wpapp1
       MYSQL_USER: wpapp1
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wpapp1
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - mysql
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - wpapp1_wordpress:/var/www/html
     restart: always
     container_name: wpapp1_wordpress
     networks:
       - traefik_network
     labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wpapp1.example.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_network"
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpapp1
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wpapp1
volumes:
    wpapp1_mysql:
      name: wpapp1_mysql
    wpapp1_wordpress:
      name: wpapp1_wordpress
networks:
    traefik_network:
      external:
         name: traefik_network
```

and here is my `wpapp2.yaml` file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - wpapp2_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     container_name: wpapp2_mysql
     networks:
       - traefik_network
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wpapp2
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wpapp2
       MYSQL_USER: wpapp2
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wpapp2
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - mysql
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - wpapp2_wordpress:/var/www/html
     restart: always
     container_name: wpapp2_wordpress
     networks:
       - traefik_network
     labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wpapp2.example.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_network"
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpapp2
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wpapp2
volumes:
    wpapp2_mysql:
      name: wpapp2_mysql
    wpapp2_wordpress:
      name: wpapp2_wordpress
networks:
    traefik_network:
      external:
         name: traefik_network
```

So now i expect traefik to route based on the hostnames `wpapp1.example.com` and `wpapp2.example.com` BUT traefik is loadbalancing traffic!!!

So when i go to `http:/wpapp1.example.com`, traefik is loadbalancing it between the two apps and same for the other hostnames. Now sure what is going on here since i specifically add the `traefik.frontend.rule`

I mean how in the hell is that happening?
I have spent hours to figure what is going on and before i go insane i decided to some here to get some help on what is going on here.

Comment: Are you sure it's traefik load balancing and not WordPress load balancing to the duplicate mysql instances in the same traefik network?

Comment: well not sure..what do i do to not make that happen? lets assume its wordpress doing that..because i just checked logs and i see that even database are getting loadbalanced too..i mean i have docker-compose so why isn't there separation between the apps? am not like exposing ports on host so not sure why docker is behaving like this

Comment: Put mysql on a different network, easiest is to not put it on a network at all and let compose make the default network. Then put WordPress on both the traefik and default networks (the default network name is "default").

Comment: i have tried using different networks for the apps..but then traefik does not work when i have apps in another network..so anyone that can help with best way to segment these apps behind traefik..will appreciate it

Comment: i will like to give my own network names rather than use default network..and when i tried doing that traefik did not pick up anything and was getting gateway timeouts..so how can i specify different networks for mysql and then have wordpress on traefik network and the custom network for the different apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your database on a different network. Otherwise WordPress will RR load balance to the two mysql instances in the same docker network (that's the expected behavior when you have two containers with the same alias on the same network). You can do that with the default network:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: unless-stopped
     networks:
       - db
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wpapp
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wpapp
       MYSQL_USER: wpapp
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wpapp
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - mysql
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - wordpress:/var/www/html
     restart: unless-stopped
     networks:
       - traefik
       - db
     labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wpapp1.example.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_network"
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpapp
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wpapp
volumes:
    mysql:
    wordpress:
networks:
    db:
    traefik:
      external:
         name: traefik_network
```

Comment: can i use custom network name rather than use `default`? can i use like `db_network` or something custom?

Comment: making it unique is not a problem...i think i just did that and still getting issues

Comment: you didn't give the db network a name declaration for specific name? `name: db`?

Comment: so yes i have this now and am still getting issues...i just did for wpapp1 and still getting the url loadbalanced via traefik, so not sure where the loadbalancing is happening but its happeing still even with separating db network

Comment: If you only update app1, and try to connect to app1, and app1 tries to connect to it's database, wouldn't app1 be able to see the second database that is still on the traefik network?

Comment: perfect!!! you are right...all works now..i know understand the whole networking thing better now..thanks a lot